# Linq Query Troubles

Tags: c#, linq

I have a DB that looks like [this](https://gyazo.com/58d6ca1c299b4f4c3e9dca8122004240) and I need a query that returns all the categories sorted into a list, and should also return any category that matches companyID.

This is the original query

```
var ROEBCategories = (from c in db.Content_Category select c).OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId).AsParallel().ToList();
```

This is my attempted query

```
var roebCategories = (from c in db.Content_Category
                                      where c.CompanyId == rawData.CompanyId || (!(from c2 in db.Content_Category select c2.CategoryId).Contains(c.CategoryId) && (!c.CompanyId.HasValue))
                                      select c).OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId).AsParallel().ToList();
```

Currently the orignal query returns all 15, and the new one returns 0. I want the new one to return 14 when the categoryID is something other than 15, but I want it to return the last category when it is 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should simply look like this:

```
var roebCategories = db.Content_Category
                       .Where(c => c.CompanyId == null || c.CompanyId == rawData.CompanyId)
                       .OrderBy(x => x.CategoryId)
                       .ToList();
```

The first part of the `Where` matches all categories that have no `CompanyId`, and the second part matches all categories with the given company id.

So when `rawData.CompanyId` is `15`, you get all 15 rows. If it's `null`, you get only the 14 rows where `CompanyId` is null.

Comment: That is awesome! Just excatly what I wanted/needed. I have such a hard time writing linq queries but this one is also really easy to read. :)